# relationships in groups (+user & friends)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

i have 3 tables like this

```
Users table
    id    | name
    -------------
    1     |  s1
    2     |  s2
    3     |  s3
    4     |  s4
    5     |  s5
    6     |  s6

friends table
friendID | user_a | user_b
--------------------
1        |   1    |   2
2        |   3    |   1
3        |   4    |   2
4        |   1    |   3

groups table 
id       | groupid | groupname
------------------------------
1        |   1    |     in01
2        |   2    |     in02
3        |   3    |     in03
4        |   1    |     in01
```

I want to run this query: **Between any of the groups most relationships?**
This is my current query, but it doesn't work

```
SELECT g.groupname, count(f.FriendId) as kol
FROM users a
left join groups g on g.id=a.id
left join friends f on f.friendid=a.id
group by kol;
```

i even have no idea, what the problem with this query

Comment: What is the relationship between `groups` and the other two tables?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your schema is not normalized. It violates the normalization rule called repeating groups (First Normal Form (1NF).  Because of this it is difficult to even determine what it means or what you want.

How can the groups tables have multiple rows with the same groupId and Group name? (groups.id 1 & 4).  Clearly this table is not a table of groups.  What is it then? Whatever it is, what is its relationship to the other tables?